# How to configure HTTPS support in squid3

Tags: https, proxy, debian, squid

I have vps, and i would like to configure my squid support HTTPS proxy.
I have configured http proxy and is work, but not support https.

question

- How to configure HTTPS proxy in squid3?

This is my squid.conf configuration details.

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 21 # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https
acl Safe_ports port 70 # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210 # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280 # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488 # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591 # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777 # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl larang url_regex -i "/etc/squid3/larang.txt"
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny larang
http_access allow all
http_port 143 transparent
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line `http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports` is blocking connection to your non SSL_ports.  Squid blocks by default: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SecurityPitfalls#The_Safe_Ports_and_SSL_Ports_ACL

You only want to allow SSL connects to reverse proxies.  Assuming that, put this at the top of your squid.conf:

```
https_port 443 cert=/path/to/CertAuth/testcert.cert key=/path/to/CertAuth/testkey.pem defaultsite=mywebsite.mydomain.com vhost
cache_peer 10.112.62.20 parent 80 0 no-query originserver login=PASS name=websiteA

acl sites_server_1 dstdomain websiteA.mydomain.com
cache_peer_access websiteA allow sites_server_1
http_access allow sites_server_1

(extracted from: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/SslWithWildcardCertifiate)
```

You will want to read all documentation though.

Here is more information on squid and SSL (Definitely Read): http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS

Comment: I think the '!' in '!SSL_ports' means NOT so it's blocking all ports that are NOT SSL ports.

Comment: You are right, this line in fact means: "Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports"